# Issues Still With Import Backup dat.file

Tags: bitcoin-core

My computer has Windows 7 professional operating system. 
I have my Wallet now synced as up-to-date.   I followed instructions from earlier post as follows:

Then you have to localize your Bitcoin folder. For Windows, it should be here:

%APPDATA%\Bitcoin

In that folder, there should be a wallet.dat file.

If you have currently no bitcoins in your wallet, you can just delete that file and replace it with your backup.
If you have some bitcoins in this wallet as well, backup that wallet file as well, or send all the coins to an address from your backed up wallet.
When you placed the other wallet.dat file in place, you should run Bitcoin-Qt with the -rescan option. Here's how to do that in Windows:

Go to C:\Program Files (x86)\Bitcoin using Windows Explorer.**[My Bitcoin foldes in Only in Program Files Folder]**
In that folder, hold shift and right-click and select Open command window here (picture). **[I do not See this Choice]**
In the command prompt, type bitcoin-qt.exe -rescan and hit enter (picture).

Therefore, main issue in have rescan option work.  Is there any other way to get this option to work inside Bitcoin Core Wallet application?

Comment: Where did you read the comment that you need to start with `-rescan`? This has not been necessary for many years now, as the wallet will detect the file is out of date and rescan from wherever is needed.

Answer (score 2):

From [Microsoft's documentation on how to open a command prompt window](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/open-a-command-prompt-window):

> Open the Command Prompt window by clicking the Start button, clicking All Programs, clicking Accessories, and
>   then clicking Command Prompt.

Also:

> Here's another way to open a Command Prompt window: Click the Start
>   button. In the Search box, type Command
>   Prompt, and then, in the list of results, double-click Command Prompt.

Once you do that use the `cd` command to "change directory" to wherever Bitcoin is installed to (probably `C:\Program Files (x86)\Bitcoin` or `C:\Program Files\Bitcoin`).  From there you should be able to type `bitcoin-qt.exe -rescan` and be on your way!

Comment: Also note @Pieter's comment on the question, how `-rescan` is not necessary.